# How to merge odt files in Python

Tags: python, merge, aspose, aspose.words, odt

I have several odt files, and I would like to merge them into a new one.

I am using [relatorio](https://relatorio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickexample.html#template) library to read the odt files.

```
from relatorio.templates.opendocument import Template
from os.path import dirname, join

odt_1 = Template(source='', filepath='report_test_1_fulled.odt')
odt_2 = Template(source='', filepath='report_test_2_fulled.odt')
```

In order to merge them into one I have tried two options without success:

1. Use [Aspose library](https://products.aspose.com/words/python-net/conversion/odt-to-doc/) to convert them to .docx and then do the merge. But when installing the library `pip install aspose-words` I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aspose-words (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aspose-words
```

I think that this might be because my computer operative system is macOS Catalina, and this does not fullfil the [requirements](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/system-requirements/).

2. Merge both odt files, but I cannot figure out how.

¿Any suggestion? The final goal is to end up with one .odt or .docx containing both.

Answer (score 0):

To combine two documents using Aspose.Words you can use [Document.append_document](https://reference.aspose.com/words/python-net/aspose.words/document/append_document/) method.

```py
dstDoc = aw.Document("documentA.odt")
srcDoc = aw.Document("documentB.odt")

# Append the source document to the destination document.
# Pass format mode to retain the original formatting of the source document when importing it.
dstDoc.append_document(srcDoc, aw.ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING)

dstDoc.save("out.odt")
```

You can learn more about appending and  inserting documents here:
https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/insert-and-append-documents/

PS: You are right, currently Aspose.Words for Python does not support MacOS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i need to do it without using Aspose because of the restriction of the operative system. Thanks!